# Enforce ordering of OData items even when $top is used

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, iqueryable

I have a `DbSet<Items>` collection.

The primary key is a Guid.  I don't want to order by this primary key.  I want to order by an editable decimal property named "Order".

The code I have is very simple, and it works great until the user puts a "$top" parameter into the request:

```
public class ItemsController : ApiController
{
    protected DbContext ctx = // ...

    // GET api/documents
    [EnableQuery()]
    public IQueryable<Item> Get()
{
    return ctx.Items.OrderBy(o => o.Order).AsQueryable();
}
```

When the user puts "$top" into the query string, the order gets all messed up (it presumably forces the ordering to be done by the primary key, for consistent paging results -- however, in my situation, this is having the opposite effect, it's preventing me from having consistent paging results).

I've tried moving `.AsQueryable()` to be earlier in the query (before the `.OrderBy(...)` clause), I've tried it without the `.AsQueryable()`, I've tried it with two AsQueryables, etc.

There are going to be a *lot* of items in this table, so it needs to be done via an `IQueryable` (enumerating all of the items on the web server via `IEnumerable` is not an option here).

The only thing that has worked so far is passing in "$orderby=Order" from the client, but I don't want to force that (seems like it will get forgotten easily).

1.) Is there anything I can do to make ordering by my `Order` property the default behavior here?

2.) Or failing that, is there anyway to trick WebApi / OData into thinking that a custom "$orderby=Order" clause was specified?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To override default sort order, you need to set property EnsureStableOrdering of EnableQueryAttribute to false, like describe [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn747012(v=vs.118).aspx):

> A true value indicates the original query should be modified when
>   necessary to guarantee a stable sort order. A false value indicates
>   the sort order can be considered stable without modifying the query.
>   Query providers that ensure a stable sort order should set this value
>   to false. The default value is true.

So in your code, changes the action attribute like this:

```
// GET api/documents
[EnableQuery(EnsureStableOrdering = false)]
public IQueryable<Item> Get()
{
    return ctx.Items.OrderBy(o => o.Order).AsQueryable();
}
```

Comment: Very strange; I tried this several times (with full clean / rebuilds too) when I posted this on Friday, and it just plain didn't work.  Today it worked.  Maybe the visual studio web server needed to recycle?

Comment: Hi! Maybe yep... sometimes I have to restart the VS IIS Express instance to make things refresh.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually invoke the odata in your controller. This should create the proper sorted IQueryable and then apply the $top and any other odata like $filter and $skip. Now you don't have to return an IQueryable which was causing the problem because the actual query was being executed later in the pipeline.

```
public class ItemsController : ApiController
{
    protected DbContext ctx = // ...

    public IEnumerable<Item> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Item> odata)
    {
        var collection = ctx.Items.OrderBy(o => o.Order);

        if (odata == null)
        {
            //return a default max size of 100
            return collection.Take(100).ToList();
        }

        var results = odata.ApplyTo(collection.AsQueryable()) as List<Item>;

        //still provide a max incase the $top wasn't specified.
        //you could check the odata to see if $top is there or not.
        return results.Take(100);
    }
}
```

More information can be found in the [WebApi documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options#ODataQueryOptions).

Comment: Upvoted for interesting solution.  The above attributey thing started working for me today, but this looks like a good backup in case the other starts acting up.